# Inputing a word then outputing them with slashes between each letter leads to error

Tags: java, eclipse

its my first year coding and I was doing a homework problem and i ran into a little error.

My homework problem was to input a word then output it with slashes inbetween each letter such as:

Apple -->  A / p / p / l / e

I managed to get to this point:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Enter a word --> ");

        String word = input.nextLine();
        worksheet(word);
    }

}

private static void worksheet(String word) {

    for (int i = 0; i < word.charAt(word.length() - 1); i++) {
        System.out.print(word.charAt(i) + " / ");
    }System.out.println(" ");

}
```

My console ends up looking like this

```
    Enter a word --> apple
    a / p / p / Exception in thread "main" l / e / 
    java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 5
        at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
        at worksheet.Worksheet11.worksheet(Worksheet11.java:22)
        at worksheet.Worksheet11.main(Worksheet11.java:14)
```

I'm not sure what this means, could someone please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the index instead of content:

```
private static void worksheet(String word) {

    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        System.out.print(word.charAt(i) + " / ");
    }System.out.println(" ");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The loop exit is wrong, use

```
 for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
```